# Is it possible to open a safari on Deeplink and move it to a specific website?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I am implementing a response web application that can also be used on mobile.

I want to implement a push notification service, and I plan to implement it using an external SNS application called Kakao Talk.

A message containing a deep link is sent to the user on KakaoTalk, and when the user clicks this deep link, I want to display a safari looking at my homepage on the mobile phone screen.

Like these,

[image]

I want to know if the way I want to implement is possible or if there is another way to implement this business logic equally.

Comment: try this

`guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {
            return
        }
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try Like This**

```
func openURL(url: URL) {
                
    guard UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {return}

    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

}
```

Comment: Can we go to safari right away when we click the uri link on an external application? An application called Kakao Talk forces Uri to use its in-app browser. @Muhanmmad Ahmad

Comment: yes @Jun that's Right
And accept the answer if thats right and answer did Helped you